# Pass variable servlet to jsp page appengine project

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets

I try to pass a simple string variable to my page index.jsp but without success:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HexoSkin_GAEServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        String dateStr = "2014.07.07.19:40";
        request.setAttribute("dateStr", dateStr);

        // I try
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        // Or
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

My index.jsp is under the folder "war." My project is a web application project (appengine)
And in my page.jsp:

```
<% 
    String attribut = (String) request.getAttribute("dateStr");
    // Return always null
    out.println("VALUE :" +attribut);
%>
```

I also tried Session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("dateStr",dateStr);
String attribut2 =  (String) session.getAttribute("dateStr") ;
```

Here's my web.xml in case it helps:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HexoSkin_GAE</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myapp.HexoSkin_GAEServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HexoSkin_GAE</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hexoskin_gae</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Did I miss some configuration part?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write, what was the problem (no value or exception). Try to use either:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

or

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Because method from ServletContext only allows path starting with the /

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried but it does not change. I receive always null on the side of jsp. Any idea ? Does I have to configure something in web.xml or another file ?

Comment: What is the page you are forwarding index.jsp, or page.jsp, because I'm a bit confused. Is this code piece of index.jsp or something else?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to display value in page.jsp  but actually  you are redirecting request to index.jsp.